delete[] causes "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer"
I have this program, a WIP assembler that only lexes right now:
int main() {
    std::cout << "\nzazz assembler\n" << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<LexerInstance> lexer = std::make_unique<LexerInstance>();
    // Test input
    std::string source = "-off 0xFFFC0000\n-entry start\n\nstart:\n\tmv mri, interrupt_table\n";
    lexer->loadSource(source);
    LexerTokenData tokens = lexer->retrieveTokens();
    if (tokens.token_data == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Error: tokens: " << tokens.token_count << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < tokens.token_count; i++) {
        std::cout << "\tToken: " << tokens[i].value << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
    // Seg fault on `delete[] this->token_data` in `~LexerTokenData()`
}


As the comment notes, my debugging has led me to locate the source of the error to originate when (implicitly, because stack) calling the ~LexerTokenData() destructor; more specifically, when deleting the token_data array.
This is the LexerInstance::retrieveTokens() method where the LexerTokenData is generated:
LexerTokenData LexerInstance::retrieveTokens() {
    if (!this->tokens_loaded) {
        int status = this->generate_tokens();
        if (status < 0) {
            LexerTokenData token_return = LexerTokenData();
            token_return.token_data = nullptr;
            token_return.token_count = status;
            return token_return;
        }
    }
    LexerTokenData token_return = LexerTokenData();
    token_return.token_data = new LexerToken[this->tokens->size()];
    wmemcpy((wchar_t *)(token_return.token_data), (wchar_t *)(this->tokens->data()), (this->tokens->size() * sizeof(LexerToken)) / sizeof(wchar_t));
    token_return.token_count = this->tokens->size();
    return token_return;
}

This is the ~LexerTokenData() destructor:
LexerTokenData::~LexerTokenData() {
    // The actual error arises in the line below
    delete[] this->token_data;
}

And finally, this is the output of the program:
zazz assembler

        Token: -off
        Token: 0xFFFC0000
        Token: -entry
        Token: start
        Token: start:
        Token: mv
        Token: mri,
        Token: interrupt_table
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
<ABORT>

I know that the munmap_chunk() function is a Linux system call, and this error arises usually when freeing an allocation not made by the allocator. However, I cannot locate any mix-ups in the addresses. Other than this error arising at the end of the program, the program works exactly as intended so far. It seems to be an issue that deals with compiler/system semantics, and I'm not well versed enough to debug this with confidence.
There are no compiler errors, or even any warnings.
For what this is worth, however, I isolated the specific error to this line, in
bits/new_allocator.h:
#if __cpp_aligned_new
    if (alignof(_Tp) > __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__)
      {
        _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE(_GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC(__p, __n),
                     std::align_val_t(alignof(_Tp)));
        return;
      }
#endif
    _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE(_GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC(__p, __n));
    // It occurs here, when __p is "interrupt_table" and __n is a nonsensically large number
    // How the execution followed to this state, I am completely unsure
      }


EDIT: Relevant type definitions:
typedef struct {
    std::string value;
    LexerTokenType type; // enum
} LexerToken;

class LexerTokenData {

public:
    LexerTokenData();
    ~LexerTokenData();
    LexerToken operator[](uint64_t index);
    LexerToken* token_data;
    uint64_t token_count;

};

class LexerInstance {

public:
    LexerInstance();
    ~LexerInstance();

    int loadSource(std::string& source);
    LexerTokenData retrieveTokens();
    LexerFilePosition getHeadPosition();

// Mfw when I accidentally follow the correct naming convention for private methods
private:
    int generate_tokens();
    LexerTokenType get_token_type(std::string text);
    std::string* source_text;
    uint64_t source_text_size;
    std::vector<LexerToken>* tokens;
    bool tokens_loaded;
    uint64_t lex_head_index;

};

And the full code:
https://pst.innomi.net/paste/dymz7fh7ch39mp5htqss2zvv
I cannot share any more code, because there is no more to provide.
NOTE: I am a native C programmer, and I'm dipping my toes into C++ to expand my horizons. I write my C++ code with a lot of subconscious C-style biases, which should help explain my memcpy tendencies and whatnot.

You REALLY don't want to memcpy() into a C++ object. Besides, from the looks of it, you're dividing the size on your copy, so you're only copying half of the data you want to copy...

What is the definition of LexerTokenData? The memcpy seems a bit suspect. You are corrupting memory somewhere and that could be it. If you have AddressSanitizer available I'd use it to see if you can catch the problem where it happens. A [mcve] would be helpful.

Please try to create a [mre] to show us.



I divide the size by sizeof(wchar_t) because wmemcpy copies by wchar_t.


I'm doubtful the memcpy is the root issue because the data I copy is correct, as the program output demonstrates. Although, I will opt to find an alternative.



You may be doubtful about the memcpy being the issue, but you're also here asking why you have a memory corruption problem. Best not to dismiss anything at this point.

Okay. Well, I created the minimal reproducible example as requested. My code is not public on GitHub yet because I am not proud of the current state of the program.

That isn't a [mcve]. I could copy/paste/compile an actual example. Anyway, your problem is using memcpy to overwrite a std::string. You can't do that.

(wchar_t *)(token_return.token_data) as far as I can see the type of token_data is completely unrelated to wchar_t so definitely undefined behaviour

I understand your memcpy bias. Just know memcpy should hardly ever be needed in current C++. That's what C++ has copy constructors for.  The same is true for new/delete, if you want a collection of something use std::vector, if you need to call virtual functions allocate class instances with std::make_unique

Hint: use std::copy for C++ types. There is also never a good reason to use wmemcpy in such a convoluted way, even in C. What happens when the size of the struct is not divisible by sizeof(wchar_t)?

I stopped using memcpy, and made a simple copy function that uses the string copy constructor to copy the string and the type. Now, I do not get that error, I just get a segfault, in a different manner...

Obvious rule of three problem in LexerTokenData The simple answer is don't use pointers.

@austanss What do you think happens to the token_data pointer when your LexerTokenData object is copied? Obviously the answer is that the pointer is copied to the new object. So now you have two pointers pointing at the same data. Now what do you think happens when those objects are destroyed? The same pointer gets deleted twice, resulting (most likely) in a crash.

@austanss As I said the simple answer is not to use pointers, but if you must use them then you must correctly handle the pointer in your copy constructor and assignment operator. Google for the 'rule of three' for more details about this topic (or look at the duplicate).

The biggest issue I can see is that you're using too many pointers. Especially, you almost never need a pointer to a container.

Well, @Homer512, to be a smart arse, I’d say that the indivisibility wouldn’t matter in C because in C i can just use the byte-sized memcpy.

@Someprogrammerdude Force of habit, I guess. I haven’t really figured out all the semantics of C++ yet, so I just default to C practices when in doubt

You can use memcpy in C++, too. Guess what std::copy compiles to for types that are trivially copyable?  Plain old C memmove. If anything, C++ required memcpy in places before bit_cast was introduced. As noted before, casting unrelated types to wchar_t* violates type aliasing rules. Casting to void* for memcpy would not.

@austanss so I just default to C practices when in doubt -- And then you will get confused when you do things like memcpy or memset into a type that is not trivially-copyable, and things start to fall apart.  Such types (non-trivially-copyable types) do not exist in C, so you never get those errors.

I'm a little confused about the use of wchar_t. I don't see anything in the code I can see that suggests wide strings. If your source is a std::string how did you end up with a wide string somewhere?

@austanss See this.  Note what struct is and is not trivially-copyable.  The one with std::string cannot be used as part of a memset or memcpy invocation.  All your memcpy did to the std::string is to rip it to shreads by destroying the internals of the object.
